# How to Disable MVC Dropdown menu client side Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im beginer for the MVC , Im develop the MVC project i have a some dropdown menu, i want to remove client slide validation how can i do it. i was removed but not work

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Ach, new SelectList(ViewBag.AtList4, "AtId", "AName"), " Select a A", new { Class = "form-control dd", title = "aa", style = "width:175px;height:30px; margin-top:6px;font-size:small;" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Ach)
                        </div>
```

model

```
[Key]

public int ItemTemplateId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("MainGroup")]

public int MainGroupId { get; set; }

public virtual MainGroup MainGroup { get; set; }
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]

[ForeignKey("SubGruop")]
public int SubGruopId { get; set; }

public virtual SubGroup SubGruop { get; set; }

public int Ach { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there are `Required` data annotation on the model `Ach` property?

Comment: Im removed the Required , but not work

Comment: can i remove the  unobtrusive script file?

Comment: No you can't just remove unobtrusive, this adheres to the attributes on your view model.  Please can you post your view model

Comment: im added my model.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the property `Ach` to a nullable `int` and then no value will be acceptable:

```
public int? Ach { get; set; }
```

I anticipate that setting this value to nullable isn't acceptable, because you don't want null values for the property within your database. Keep reading...

I notice that your View Model has `[Key]`, `[ForeignKey]` and `virtual` properties, which suggests to me that you're using your domain models as view models.

You should really have a whole new class that has a specific use as a View Model for your page that contains the minimum number of properties to hold only the values that are required to display the view.

Comment: Sir,  Thanks a lot finaly its realy working, thanks for your solution, :)

Comment: Great stuff, glad to have helped